# Hibernate - time format annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, time-format

I've in DB (mysql) a column type format **time** e.g. 12:30:00
I use for column in Hibernate domain the follow code

```
private LocalTime timeStart;  

@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsTime")
@Column(name="time_start")
public LocalTime getTimeStart(){
      return timeStart;
}
```

If I print the value I have **12:00:00.000**
Can I have directly the pattern hh:mm without string trasformation,If yes How?
TNX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public LocalTime getTimeStart(){
      return timeStart;
}   

public String getTimeStartAsString(){
      return timeStart == null ? "" : timeStart.toString("hh:mm");
}
```

Comment: I just changed hh:mm into  HH:mm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) instance to format a date object from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm").print( timeStart );
```